# node github API

Tags: node.js, github

I tried to hit my git hub API to get some data.
I have my Client ID and Client Secret. 
Code which I tried put is below:

```
var GitHubApi = require('github');
var github = new GitHubApi({
  version: "3.0.0",
  debug: true,
  protocol: "https",
  host: "api.github.com",
  timeout: 5000,
  authenticate: {
    type: "oauth",
    key: process.env['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'],
    secret: process.env['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET']
  }
});
```

and

```
hitting API with :

    loadUserFromServer2 : function (username){
      github.user.get({
        user: username,
      },function(err,res){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      });
    }
```

I am getting the error that (..)

> { [Error: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}]
>   [error]   (..),
>     code: 401 }

What am I missing in my authorization ?

It still does not work. I was able to have the access as a normal user.

My code is :

```
github.authorization.create({
  "scopes" : ["user"],
  "note" : "admin server rights",
  "type" : "oauth",
  "app": {
    "name" : "gitHubNetwork",
    "client_id" : process.env['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'],
    "client_secret" : process.env['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET']
  }
});
```

But I am still getting below reply:

> { [Error: {"message":"Requires authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#oauth-authorizations-api"}]

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ing `process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID` and `process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET` to ensure that they are set to the proper values?

Comment: yes, all good ; I used same credentials via jquery $.get() in my client app and it worked but I wanted to move it to the server side and i am stuck ..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I should have used `github.getFrom` function instead of `github.get`. It is working now.
It seems like different authentication is needed for .get method.

Comment: It still does not work.. I could do but queries as a normal user.